# Sum up two SELECT values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question according a query. I want to sum up two SELECT values (old value + new value from another table) and update the old value like this:

```
$query = mysql_query ("UPDATE Inventory 
                       SET quantity = (
                                       SELECT quantity 
                                       FROM Inventory 
                                       WHERE productname='$AwaitedToMOVE'
                                      ) +
                                      (
                                       SELECT quantity 
                                       FROM Awaited 
                                       WHERE OrderName='$Awaited'
                                      )
                       WHERE productname='$AwaitedToMOVE'; ");
```

How can I fix the sum?

Comment: `SUM()` http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-aggregate-functions.aspx

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: I recommend using PDO, because named placeholders are incredibly useful and makes it easy to maintain queries, keep them secure, and readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, something like this should work perfectly.

```
$query = mysql_query("
    UPDATE Inventory iv
    SET quantity = quantity + (
      SELECT quantity 
      FROM Awaited aw
      WHERE aw.productname = iv.productname
    )
    WHERE iv.productname = '$AwaitedToMOVE';
");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just `SUM()` the 2 fields you select in the 2 subqueries like this.

```
$query = mysql_query (
              "UPDATE Inventory 
               SET quantity = (
                               SELECT SUM(quantity) 
                               FROM Inventory 
                               WHERE productname='$AwaitedToMOVE'
                              ) +
                              (
                               SELECT SUM(quantity) 
                               FROM Awaited 
                               WHERE OrderName='$Awaited'
                              )
               WHERE productname='$AwaitedToMOVE'; ");
```

Comment: I think I might have been misunderstood. What I want to do is sum up the two select values - not take the sum of one select row within table Inventory or Table Awaited. The query:

$query = mysql_query (
              "UPDATE Inventory 
               SET quantity = (
                               SELECT ...
                              ) +
                              (
                               SELECT ...
                              )
               WHERE productname='$AwaitedToMOVE'; ");

is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I would separate those queries into three different ones, and use PHP to calculate the sum.

```
$query_initial_value = mysql_query('SELECT quantity FROM Inventory WHERE productname = "' . $AwaitedToMove . '"');
$query_new_value = mysql_query('SELECT quantity FROM Awaited WHERE OrderName = "' . $Awaited . '"');
$sum = $query_initial_value + $query_new_value;
$query_update = mysql_query('UPDATE Inventory SET quantity = ' . $sum . ' WHERE productname = "' . $AwaitedToMove . '"');
```

Comment: While running 3 queries is a possibility and minimally simplifies the SQL, it makes the code much less manageable and uses a lot more resources, since SQL is usually much more performant than PHP, and running multiple queries is more time spent connecting tothe MySQL server/database

Comment: Plus it opens up possibilities of concurrency problems, if, say, a new order is inserted by a different request between the SELECT statements and the UPDATE.

Comment: @Jakar Thanks for your comment! I haven't thought about performance like that before, but it makes a lot of sense. Also, I haven't known of MySQL SUM() feature; the answer above looks better now that I've learned about it!

Comment: Early in learning PHP/MySQL, instead of using `JOIN`s, cuz I didn't realize they existsed, I would run one query, then loop through the results and run queries based on the results, and end up running like 10-20 queries per request on some pages. Until all of a sudden, my dataset was larger, and everything just stopped functioning. Then I had to actually learn MySQL lol.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
UPDATE Inventory SET Inventory.quantity = 
    ( Inventory.quantity +
         (SELECT Awaited.quantity FROM Awaited WHERE Awaited.OrderName = 'Condition') ) 
            WHERE Inventory.productname = 'Condition'
```